# Implement a library to track all events in an app

Tags: android

I am trying to create a library, lets call it L. A company has an android app, say A.

L can be linked to A such that in the codes of A, the dev just needs to add something like:

L l = new L("client_id")
l.startTrack();

Now L should be able to track all clicks that happens in A and pass to a server for logging. AppSee is a product that is already doing this.

I am wondering how can i intercept every user action to get the action target name (button title? textfield?)

Thank you!

Comment: plus one, same thing I want, have you find any way? @Mark

Answer (score 6):

What you are asking is EventTracking, like in GoogleAnalytics. But the approach you are doing is different. In Google analytic one needs to start event to event tracker. Like say you have a 3 buttons and you need to track each button separately, there you put 3 separate events trackers.

If you want to track all the events going through the activity you need to implement Activity's `onInterceptTouchEvent()`. Whenever a touch event happens in an activity, it passes through the said method above.

As Google says

> Implement this method to intercept all touch screen motion events.
>   This allows you to watch events as they are dispatched to your
>   children, and take ownership of the current gesture at any point.

with caution

> Using this function takes some care, as it has a fairly complicated
>   interaction with View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent), and using it requires
>   implementing that method as well as this one in the correct way.

For more Event details, [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).

Comment: Hi, in this case, I'll need to implement "onInterceptTouchEvent()" on every activity I wanted to track, right? Cause I'm making a library for tracking now, it doesn't sound good to do that

Comment: Object orientedly speaking no, You need to create a base Activity and extent all activity through it. It that manner, all touch events will pass through your activity.

Comment: What if the client app is using subclass of activity eg. AppCompatActivity, ActionBarActivity, FragmentActivity?

Comment: Yeah that could be the case.

Comment: @MarkKWH In that case you can supply several versions of your activity, `AppCompatTrackedActivity` (that extends `AppCompatActivity`), `ActionBarTrackedActivity` (that extends `ActionBarActivity`) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

OnClickListener is a Interface. so you can implementing it's in any class

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. Since every control on the screen is a subclass of view, you can do something like this:

```
public static void logClicksOnMe(View v){
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           //TODO Log code
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously that would destroy the listeners you already set on such object, but you can do something like this:

```
public static void setLoggedListener(View v, View.OnClickListener listener){
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           //TODO Log code
           if(listener!=null) listener.onClick(v);
        }
    });
}
```

The developer will have to set the listeners manually, but he already has to, so neither the workload or the code should change much. The advantage over the onInterceptTouchEvent() activity interface is that you can absolutely control which view are gonna be tracked and the developer is not constrained to use your abstract activity (let's say he already is using other abstract activities from third parties, like SlidingActivity or things like that.), so the maintenance and implementations efforts are pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

```
Not exactly, actually there is something more easier, you can ask them to inherit there activities from your activity
 eg. A extends L;
Do this in following steps. 

1. Create the library(say L is com.click.counter), with event handles counter like explained in many reply above, using view.onclicklistner. In onclick event, The only difference is use package name. As context is of the app which is calling the library, you can use
Context::getPackageName
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29

2. onclick events, you may log and sync in one go, at end of day/scheduled time, or on every click. you may use httphandler for that 
See 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/helloworld?hl=en

2. Create a test apk(A),add the library as dependency in gradle. 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.click.counter'
  }

3. Inherit all the activity in test apk from class A
```